# Powershell hyphen argument color

Tags: powershell, colors

I want to change the color of the `-a, --All` arguments in Powershell. I have changed the string and command colors of my in Powershell like this.

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind String -ForegroundColor Cyan
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Command -ForegroundColor Magenta
```

I cannot find how to change the hyphen arguments color.

Is it under `Set-PSReadlineOption` or somewhere else?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're looking for the `Parameter` token kind:

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Parameter -ForegroundColor Red
```

The above will color parameter tokens (like `-a`) red, but not bare string tokens prefixed with `--` (like `--All`), since they're technically not considered parameter tokens by the parser.

---

As [Rabeez Riaz notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978897/powershell-hyphen-argument-color/44979367#comment95962959_44979367), in PSReadLine 2.0 the syntax is slightly different:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{ Parameter = 'Red' }
```

The new syntax allows you to set multiple token colors simultaneously:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{
  Parameter  = 'Red'
  String     = 'Cyan'
  Command    = 'Green'
}
```

Comment: The updated version of this should be `Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{Parameter = "Red"}`. The new argument is a semicolon separated hashtable of colors.

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is something like this:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{"Parameter"="#ff81f7"}
```